# coloring rows of a table for separated column individually

Tags: tables

We could construct a table with:

```
\begin{table*}[t]
\[
\begin{array}{@{} l *{9}{c} @{}}
\toprule
m & \multicolumn{2}{c}{J^*(m)}     & t^*(m)
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{J^{**}(m)}  & t^{**}(m)
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{J^{***}(m)} & t^{***}(m) \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){5-6} \cmidrule(lr){8-9}
& 1-1/m & 1+1/m & m\pi
& 1-3/m & 1+3/m & m\pi
& 1-5/m & 1+5/m & m\pi \\
\midrule
1 & 0   & 2   &  \pi \\
2 & 1/2 & 3/2 & 2\pi \\
3 & 2/3 & 4/3 & 3\pi & 0   & 2   & 3\pi \\
4 & 3/4 & 5/4 & 4\pi & 1/4 & 7/4 & 4\pi \\
5 & 4/5 & 6/5 & 5\pi & 2/5 & 8/5 & 5\pi & 0 & 2 & 5\pi \\
6 & 5/6 & 7/6 & 6\pi & 3/6 & 9/6 & 6\pi & 1/6 & 11/6 & 6\pi \\
7 & 6/7 & 8/7 & 7\pi & 4/7 & 10/7 & 7\pi & 2/7 & 12/7 & 7\pi \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}
\]
\end{table*}
```

of course I think we need

```
 \usepackage{framed}
 \usepackage{tabularx}
 \usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage{framed}
```

We added by paint two vertical black lines which are desired but we do not know how we can  insert them!!!

In addition, we wish to limn some rows of table as below with green, blue and red but for any separated column. How can we do that?

[image]

Comment: Horizontal rules from the `booktabs` package are not compatible with vertical lines, so I'd recommend to not use vertical lines.

Comment: But I must separate column from each other as shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are three versions of the table:

1. with colored cell backgrounds
2. with color and vertical lines + original booktabs lines
3. with color and vertical lines + hline

Please note that I have removed the `@{}` from `\begin{tabular}` since otherwise the colored backgrounds would overflow to the left and right of the table. PLease also be aware that the combination of color and lines causes some viewer dependant issues regarding "missing" lines. In the below screenshot the vertical lines seem to be missing in some rows. To see these lines, zoom in further.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[table,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\cellg}{\cellcolor{LightGreen}}
\newcommand{\cellb}{\cellcolor{LightBlue}}
\newcommand{\cellr}{\cellcolor{LightPink}}

\begin{document}


\[
\begin{array}{ l *{9}{c} }
\toprule
m & \multicolumn{2}{c}{J^*(m)}     & t^*(m)
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{J^{**}(m)}  & t^{**}(m)
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{J^{***}(m)} & t^{***}(m) \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){5-6} \cmidrule(lr){8-9}
& 1-1/m & 1+1/m & m\pi
& 1-3/m & 1+3/m & m\pi
& 1-5/m & 1+5/m & m\pi \\
\midrule
\cellg 1 & \cellg 0   & \cellg 2   &  \cellg \pi \\
2 & 1/2 & 3/2 & 2\pi \\
\cellg 3 & \cellg 2/3 & \cellg 4/3 & \cellg 3\pi & \cellb 0   & \cellb 2   & \cellb 3\pi \\
4 & 3/4 & 5/4 & 4\pi & 1/4 & 7/4 & 4\pi \\
\cellg 5 & \cellg 4/5 & \cellg 6/5 & \cellg 5\pi & \cellb 2/5 & \cellb 8/5 & \cellb 5\pi & \cellr 0 & \cellr 2 & \cellr 5\pi \\
6 & 5/6 & 7/6 & 6\pi & 3/6 & 9/6 & 6\pi & 1/6 & 11/6 & 6\pi \\
\cellg 7 & \cellg 6/7 & \cellg 8/7 & \cellg 7\pi & \cellb 4/7 & \cellb 10/7 & \cellb 7\pi & \cellr 2/7 & \cellr 12/7 & \cellr 7\pi \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}
\]

\bigskip

\[
\begin{array}{ l *{3}{c}*{2}{|ccc} }
\toprule
m & \multicolumn{2}{c}{J^*(m)}     & t^*(m)
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{J^{**}(m)}  & t^{**}(m)
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{J^{***}(m)} & t^{***}(m) \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){5-6} \cmidrule(lr){8-9}
& 1-1/m & 1+1/m & m\pi
& 1-3/m & 1+3/m & m\pi
& 1-5/m & 1+5/m & m\pi \\
\midrule
\cellg 1 & \cellg 0   & \cellg 2   &  \cellg \pi & & & & & \\
2 & 1/2 & 3/2 & 2\pi & & & & & \\
\cellg 3 & \cellg 2/3 & \cellg 4/3 & \cellg 3\pi & \cellb 0   & \cellb 2   & \cellb 3\pi \\
4 & 3/4 & 5/4 & 4\pi & 1/4 & 7/4 & 4\pi \\
\cellg 5 & \cellg 4/5 & \cellg 6/5 & \cellg 5\pi & \cellb 2/5 & \cellb 8/5 & \cellb 5\pi & \cellr 0 & \cellr 2 & \cellr 5\pi \\
6 & 5/6 & 7/6 & 6\pi & 3/6 & 9/6 & 6\pi & 1/6 & 11/6 & 6\pi \\
\cellg 7 & \cellg 6/7 & \cellg 8/7 & \cellg 7\pi & \cellb 4/7 & \cellb 10/7 & \cellb 7\pi & \cellr 2/7 & \cellr 12/7 & \cellr 7\pi \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}
\]

\bigskip

\[
\begin{array}{ l *{3}{c}*{2}{|ccc} }
\hline
m & \multicolumn{2}{c}{J^*(m)}     & t^*(m)
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{J^{**}(m)}  & t^{**}(m)
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{J^{***}(m)} & t^{***}(m) \\
\cline{2-3} \cline{5-6} \cline{8-9}
& 1-1/m & 1+1/m & m\pi
& 1-3/m & 1+3/m & m\pi
& 1-5/m & 1+5/m & m\pi \\
\hline
\cellg 1 & \cellg 0   & \cellg 2   &  \cellg \pi & & & & & \\
2 & 1/2 & 3/2 & 2\pi & & & & & \\
\cellg 3 & \cellg 2/3 & \cellg 4/3 & \cellg 3\pi & \cellb 0   & \cellb 2   & \cellb 3\pi \\
4 & 3/4 & 5/4 & 4\pi & 1/4 & 7/4 & 4\pi \\
\cellg 5 & \cellg 4/5 & \cellg 6/5 & \cellg 5\pi & \cellb 2/5 & \cellb 8/5 & \cellb 5\pi & \cellr 0 & \cellr 2 & \cellr 5\pi \\
6 & 5/6 & 7/6 & 6\pi & 3/6 & 9/6 & 6\pi & 1/6 & 11/6 & 6\pi \\
\cellg 7 & \cellg 6/7 & \cellg 8/7 & \cellg 7\pi & \cellb 4/7 & \cellb 10/7 & \cellb 7\pi & \cellr 2/7 & \cellr 12/7 & \cellr 7\pi \\
\hline
\end{array}
\]




\end{document}
```

Comment: Wonderful and fantastic